# Cleanup WordPress wp_postmeta Table

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I was looking at all the tables in my WordPress database and noticed that the `wp_postmeta` table had a lot of old and outdated information. For example, it contained a LOT of entries with meta key set to `_wp_attached_file`, `_wp_attachment_metadata`. The `_wp_attached_file` values are all links to old files that no longer exists in my WordPress gallery.

There are also some other entries from old plugins that seem redundant.

I wanted to know if there is a way for me to clean up the data in the table. I found [this article](https://teresagiesecke.wordpress.com/2017/08/30/how-to-clean-wp_postmeta-table/) after doing some research. The SQL queries listed on the page do work after I make appropriate changes to the table names.

Here are the original queries:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta pm LEFT JOIN wp_posts wp ON wp.ID = pm.post_id WHERE wp.ID IS NULL;
DELETE pm FROM wp_postmeta pm LEFT JOIN wp_posts wp ON wp.ID = pm.post_id WHERE wp.ID IS NULL;
```

I did not run the DELETE query on my database. However, running the SELECT query gave me the following result.

After seeing a lot of NULL values, I am guessing the query does select redundant values. Should I run the DELETE query now?

Also, I know just basic SQL so could not understand how the queries work. Could anyone please explain it to me?

[image]

Comment: Have you considered using a DB cleaner plugin? For example- https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-database-cleaner/ ?

Comment: _“Also, I know just basic SQL so could not understand how the queries work. Could anyone please explain it to me?”_ - for starters, go read up on what JOINs are, any halfway decent beginner’s tutorial should be able to explain that.

Comment: Just make a database backup and run the delete query and test. If something breaks, simply restore the database using the backup. Regarding what the query does, [here's a tutorial about MySQL joins](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/)

Comment: @misorude I know about JOIN but don't know what `pm` and `LEFT` is.

Comment: `pm` is simply an _alias_ for the table `wp_postmeta`, and LEFT makes the JOIN a LEFT JOIN.

Comment: `LEFT` refers to `LEFT JOIN`, which is a type of join. There are plenty of them. The link I posted in my previous comment explains them. And `pm` is an alias for the table. You can read more about aliases [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-alias/)

Comment: @misorude So `wp` is an alias for `wp_posts` right? Thanks, I understand the query now. :)

Comment: Thank you @MagnusEriksson :)

Comment: @GulJamalZim The plugin looks promising. I will give it a try and post the results. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can run the `DELETE`.  Personally, I would create a backup table of the rows that are going to be deleted, and then reference that.

The SELECT uery demonstrates the *anti-join* pattern

```
 SELECT pm.* 
   FROM wp_postmeta pm 
     -- anti-join - only return rows from pm that do NOT have a matching row in wp
   LEFT
   JOIN wp_posts wp 
     ON wp.id = pm.post_id 
  WHERE wp.id IS NULL
```

The `LEFT JOIN` is an outer join; that says return all rows from the table on the left (in this case `pm` ) along with matching rows from the table on the right ( `wp` ).

One way to think about what the outer join does is that it says if there are no matching rows in `wp`, then go ahead and create a dummy row that consists of all NULL values, and return the dummy row.

The trick in this query is the condition in the WHERE clause. Any row from `wp` that matches is guaranteed to have a non-NULL value for `wp.id`, because only non-NULL values will satisfy the equality comparison in the ON clause. Any NULL value won't be matched. (Also, its likely `id` is a column guaranteed to be non-NULL in the table.)

After the join operation, any resulting rows that have a NULL value for `wp.id` are the result of *dummy* rows generated by the outer join.  So we know there was no matching row  in `wp`.

Another way to generate an equivalent result is to use a `NOT EXISTS (correlated subquery)` predicate.

```
 SELECT pm.* 
   FROM wp_postmeta pm 
  WHERE NOT EXISTS 
        ( SELECT 1 
            FROM wp_posts wp 
           WHERE wp.id = pm.post_id
        )
```

---

I'd create a backup of the rows to be deleted:

```
 CREATE TABLE _backup_db_._backup_20190813_delete_from_pm_ 
 AS 
 SELECT pm.*
   FROM wp_postmeta pm 
     -- anti-join - only return rows from pm that do NOT have a matching row in wp
   LEFT
   JOIN wp_posts wp 
     ON wp.id = pm.post_id 
  WHERE wp.id IS NULL
```

And then I'd reference the backup table in the `DELETE`, with join that references the primary key of the target table.

Assuming here that `id` is the PRIMARY KEY in the `post_meta` table (we would need to check that, not just guess), I'd write first as a SELECT:

```
 SELECT t.*
   FROM _backup_db_._backup_20190813_delete_from_pm   s
   JOIN post_meta t 
     ON t.id = s.id
```

to test, and then convert to a delete statement by replacing the SELECT keyword with DELETE keyword

Note that it's critically important that the `*` be qualified with the table alias `t.*`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer spencer. :)

Could you please explain what the last line "Note that it's critically important that the * be qualified with the table alias t.*". meant?

Comment: Did you mean that there should be no space between `t.` and `*`?

Comment: what i meant was that the `t.` is required not optional. there is a critical difference between specifying `t.*`  vs just `*`. (i thought it important to point out the difference, given the OP query specifies just `*`)